# List of guest users via microsoft graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get a list of guest users with `Microsoft Graph explorer`. I've tried  with

```
?$filter -eq usertype
```

but it seems `usertype` is not known.

May somebody can help me with this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest'` , it works fine on my side.

**Note**: You need the permission to list users first, refer to this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thx a lot! works also for me. I try to also check if the account is enabled. What am i doing wrong here?
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq 'true'

Comment: @Thomas I got a bad request error, says `Invalid filter clause`.

Comment: this works but i think the output is not correct https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest' & AccountEnabled eq 'true'

Comment: @Thomas Not sure, but I think the result only for `userType eq 'Guest'` is correct, because I know the format of the guest's `userPrincipalName`.